# using music in discord.js not working probably

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a discord bot with `discord.js` and hosted it on `Github Actions`

When playing an audio track on youtube with:

```js
Queue.connection.play(ytdl(song.SongURL))
```

I hear it sounds like you are hearing a broken radio with a weird noise. Could anyone help?.

Comment: What do you mean by "hosting on GitHub Actions"? GitHub Actions is not a hosting service.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine this is a problem with Github Actions.

I'm not entirely familiar with the platform, but it could be that the action is exiting before it can fully play the song and leave the voice channel.

Perhaps what's happening is the action connects the bot, attempts to play the file, and then any event listener you have for the "end" of the song to leave the channel or stop playing is never executed, nor is the async call to stream the song?

That's just a guess, but try hosting it locally first and running it that way.

Comment: When i host it locally, got the same problem
Can you give me a hosting platform to try with ..

Comment: Do you have a full code example I can take a look at quickly? Just the minimum amount of code possible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: let serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
    if(!song){
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url)).on('end', () => {
        serverQueue.songs.shift();
        playSong(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on('error', () => {
        console.log(error)})
dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(75);   

a part of the a code

Comment: A few things I can think of. Firstly is the song URL correct, and the response of ytdl returning as expected? Secondly, again make sure the code is fully executing before exiting. I suspect github actions prematurely exits the code instead of waiting for anything to execute. Try putting console logs in each section of the code and checking which ones run. It's hard without a larger code sample to provide much more help. Ideally I need something I can copy, add in an API key of my own and run. Something minimal that reproduces the error so I can check properly.